# Commerce 2 Add to cart with quantity field and Product Picture

Tags: 8, commerce

I have added an image field in product variation type. Add few products to my store. Now when I am going to product detail page to add the product in cart it just shows the add to cart button without any quantity field. Also not showing Image of the product.

I tried to change the formatter to Rendered Entity, but it then only showing the picture  and price but not the add to cart button. Rendered Entity was using default view mode. So I created additional view mode through manage display of product variation type but that also didn't provide any option to show the add to cart button.

What I want is to display the product variation picture + Price + SKU + Add to Cart button with quantity field.

Please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: I think this is what you need to display the quantity field: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2854150#comment-11947785

Answer (score 4):

Please check your order item type e.g. admin/commerce/config/order-item-types/default/edit/form-display/variation_cart_form (default type)

Needed view mode is variation cart form. There is quantity field.

Also check this default view mode for your product variation type /admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types/default/edit/display

There is add to cart button.

Comment: I am able to show the quantity field using your instructions but still unable to show the price.

Answer (score 1):

The price is shown by the **purchasable_entity** field. When you create your order item type you may (is not required) select the purchasable entity type you want your order item referred to. Typically this would be a product variation type in many cases the machine name for your product variation type matches your order item type machine name, for example if your your order item type can be **cars_parts** then you may have **cars_parts** product type and **cars_parts_variation** product variation type.

Although this setting can only be set during the order item type creation so cannot be edited afterwards, but you can edit the configuration directly in the database (not recommended) or using Drush (recommended):

```
# Drush 8
drush config-edit commerce_order.commerce_order_item_type.your_order_item
# Drush 9
drush config:edit commerce_order.commerce_order_item_type.your_order_item
```

The prior command will open your terminal fav text editor just change the line which prints **purchasableEntityType: null** to your product variation type. If that is set correctly you should check the default view display for your product variation type in */admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types/YOUR_TYPE/edit/display*

To output this field in your *Add to cart* form mode just go to */admin/commerce/config/order-item-types/YOUR_TYPE/edit/form-display/add_to_cart* and drop it in place.